# Material UI Checkbox is repeating the same value twice in one instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, state

Using React and Material UI checkbox

I'm trying to have a checkbox render a state change to a specific value when it is checked.

Everything is working properly, however only on the first 2 clicks of the checkbox the state doesn't update properly

```
const [waterChecked, setWaterChecked] = React.useState(true);
const [data, setData] = useState(null);

const handleChangeWater = (event) => {
    setWaterChecked(event.target.checked);
    if (waterChecked) {
      setData([1, 2, 3, 4])
    } else if (!waterChecked) {
      setData([])
    }
  };

<ul>
            <Checkbox
              waterChecked={waterChecked}
              onChange={handleChangeWater}
              defaultChecked={false}
              inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'controlled' }}
            />
            Water
          </ul>
```

Putting a console.log(waterChcked) inside of my handleChangeWater function grants these outputs. After 5 clicks I get:

true, true, false, true, false

It works exactly as intended after the first 2 clicks, the only issue is the order is inverted because of the double true at the start.

for example 7 clicks of the checkbox outputs

true, true, false, true, false, true, false

etc..

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, I am new to react so please excuse any syntax prolems.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setWaterChecked(event.target.checked)` sets the `waterChecked` state asynchronously. Therefore, you can't use it to set the `data` state afterward. Therefore, use `event.target.checked` value to set the `data` state as follows.

```
const [waterChecked, setWaterChecked] = React.useState(true);
const [data, setData] = useState(null);

const handleChangeWater = (event) => {
    const checked = event.target.checked;
  setWaterChecked(checked);
  if (checked) {
    setData([1, 2, 3, 4]);
  } else {
    setData([]);
  }
};

<ul>
  <Checkbox
    waterChecked={waterChecked}
    onChange={handleChangeWater}
    defaultChecked={false}
    inputProps={{ "aria-label": "controlled" }}
  />
  Water
</ul>;
```

Or you can use `useEffect` to keep track on `waterChecked` state and do the necessary changes on `data` state as follows.

```
const [waterChecked, setWaterChecked] = React.useState(true);
const [data, setData] = useState(null);

const handleChangeWater = (event) => {
  setWaterChecked(event.target.checked);
};

useEffect(() => {
  if (waterChecked) {
    setData([1, 2, 3, 4]);
  } else {
    setData([]);
  }
}, [waterChecked]);

<ul>
  <Checkbox
    waterChecked={waterChecked}
    onChange={handleChangeWater}
    defaultChecked={false}
    inputProps={{ "aria-label": "controlled" }}
  />
  Water
</ul>;
```

Comment: Thanks for your speedy answer! this is exactly what I needed thank you!